# US School System

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate, education, united-states, sweden

I live in Sweden and I'm currently in the second last year of "Gymnasiet" (Senior High School), years 16-18. In Sweden, the next step is "Högskolan." Is that the same as undergraduate education in the US? Do I first need undergraduate education to attend a graduate school? Is there any difference between graduate and post-graduate education?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE! You have three questions in this post: 1) Is Högskolan the same as undergrad in the US? 2)Do I need undergrad education to get into grad school? and 3) What is the difference between graduate and post-graduate education? We encourage one post per question. That way answers can be focused, and everyone involved has the chance to earn more rep.

Comment: All right, I'll think about that the next time I post. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The stages of Gymnasiet and Högskolan correspond to the German Gymnasium and Hochschule, respectively. These do work out to the US high school and university.
2. Graduate education normally requires an undergraduate degree as a prerequisite. However, unlike in much of Europe, there is not the requirement that the bachelor's is required for a Master's in the same discipline. (That is, in the US, someone with a BS in chemistry can do a master's in chemical engineering; this is not normally possible in much of Europe.
3. Graduate and postgraduate both mean more or less the same thing in the US: education past the bachelor's level.